# Emailing of HTML formatted text only works with Gmail client

Tags: android, android-intent

I am just developing my first simple app. It generates and sends an HTML formatted email to my customers who have just purchased a product. It sends email using Intent:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("text/html"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {email}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(htmlcode));
thiscontext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

This works great if I send the email using Gmail, but I cannot find any other email client that will send an HTML formatted email. Some will be text, some will be blank. Have tried K-9, Droidmail, Innomail, android default email and others.

The thing is that I do not want to send from my Gmail account. Why do none of these work, and does anyone know of an email client that will work correctly?

Cheers

Comment: I have the same issue here with Mailbox and Yahoo mail. Has anyone ever get this working in those mail clients?